# OpenGL ES 2.0 - How can multiple views use the same renderer?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

Right now I have my `ApplicationActivity`, this activity is responsible for managing multiple views (`GLSurfaceViews`). Can / Should I have all the views set the renderer to a "global" renderer?

Code:

```
public class ApplicationActivity extends Activity 
{
    private static final String TAG = ApplicationActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private final Stack<Screen> screens = new Stack<Screen>();
    private GlRenderer glRenderer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Log.d(TAG, "Main Activity Created");

        setupGraphics();

        ChangeScreen(new MainMenu(this, glRenderer)); //Creating a new Screen sets the renderer
    }

    private void setupGraphics()
    {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        glRenderer = new GlRenderer(this);
    }


    public void Draw() //Is called by the glRenderer onDrawFrame() { mainActivity.Draw() } 
    {

    }
}
```

Its the same activity switching between `GLSurfaceViews` and by my knowledge I believe that the method `setRenderer` sets the view renderer and then starts the rendering thread (creating a new thread) but I don't want to recreate the thread every time I switch between views - may create potential problems.

So in the end I want a Renderer class just to keep graphics sepreate from business logic and such but, I don't know if using one Renderer is even possible, without setting the thread again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use Multiple Views with the same Renderer only if you properly switch out between them with `GLSurfaceView.onPause()` / `.onResume();`

My specific case:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() //Overrides onPause from Activity
{
    surfaceViews.peek().onPause();
    super.onPause();
}
```

So everytime the activity pauses I would have to pause the current View. And if the Activity resumes then resume the View also.

I also have a method called `SetView` which will either (pause and remove then change to another View) or (pause and then change to another View) this is accomplished using a `Stack`

```
public void SetView(View screen)
{   
    if (!screens.empty())
    {
        screens.peek().onPause();
        screens.pop();
    }

    screens.push(screen);
    setContentView(screens.peek());
}
```

Of course though because we are using Views instead of Activities now we must Override the `onBackPressed()` to go back to previous Views.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{       
    if (screens.size() == 1)
        super.onBackPressed();
    else
    {
        screens.pop();
        setContentView(screens.peek());
        screens.peek().onResume();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing `new GLRenderer()` you create new **instance** of your class. So there is no problem to have the same renderer used in different activities.

EDIT: I seem to misunderstand your question - if you want many GL surfaces visible at once, then no, it is not possible. But it got nothing to do with reusing renderer code.

Comment: Won't `onDrawFrame` be called multiple times then? I understand that theirs only one instance of `GLRenderer` being passed around but I'm not sure if the `GLSurfaceViews` can have a persistent `GLRenderer` with multiple calls (if any?)

Comment: No they are not all visible at the same time.

Comment: Still not clear what "not visible at the same time" mean for you. I answer this way if you got i.e. activity A with GLSurface using your renderer code and then users goes to activity B with GLSurgace - both can use the same renderer code.